# Where to ask questions about secure programming approaches?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about how / whether you can secure an Azure Mobile Services instance under a set of requirements. I am not looking for an answer with specific code examples etc. I just want an outline of how I might approach the problem, but the answer requires a specific knowledge of Azure and it's Mobile Services Back-end. Ideally, I think I am after an Azure, or Cloud Computing site, but they don't seem to exist. That aside is SO or Information Security appropriate?

Comment: SO requires you to be very concrete about coding attempts and a programming specific question, I don't know what the policies are at SE Information Security.